# How to get the hostname of an IP Address?

Tags: php

Like how these sites do it:

http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-hostname

https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-address-host-name-lookup/

Entering `23.23.171.33` gives the result `ec2-23-23-171-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

PHP's `gethostbyaddr()` does not give this result. How can performe reverse DNS lookups?

Comment: `gethostbyaddr` returns that for me.

Comment: Google is your friend: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php

Comment: He doesn't want the server's hostname, he wants the client's hostname.

Comment: really? why does it return "fastcompany.com" for me!?

Comment: Probably bad configuration of PHP or wrong DNS settings. 
You can try use `exec()` and commands like `host` or `dig`.

Comment: @Sunny Do you have an entry for this IP in your `/etc/hosts` file? That may be superceding the DNS lookup.

Comment: @Sunny Or are you running your own DNS server that has reverse DNS for your IPs?

Comment: Grr that first dupe is _wrong_.

Comment: I don't see the answer in those links, `gethostbyaddr('23.23.171.33');` is still returning "fastcompany.com" for me. @Barmar I'm not sure, where can I find more info on that?

Comment: Read the file `/etc/hosts` on the server if it's Linux. Ask your system administrator.

Comment: I don't see any mappings for that ip listed in that hosts file

Comment: and I'm not running my own dns server. Am I the only one getting this result?

Comment: Is it possible that it is being "cached" somewhere? Because "fastcompany.com" was taken from the $_POST variable and then converted to ip with gethostbyname(); maybe that association is remembered & stored somewhere...  When I test entering random IPs I seem to be getting the same results as those websites.